# Wkhtmltopdf in a Dokku app?

Tags: docker, wkhtmltopdf, dokku

I have a NodeJS/Express Dokku container. I'm trying to use a node module which just runs the wkhtmltopdf command from shell, but it can't find wkhtmltopdf.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check how `wkhtmltopdf` was installed in that image.

As mentioned in [`node-wkhtmltopdf` issues 32](https://github.com/devongovett/node-wkhtmltopdf/issues/32):

The `wkhtmltopdf` command is executed as a shell command on non-Windows systems.
Make sure the `/usr/local/bin` directory is in your `$PATH` variable. Do this by running:

```
$ sh
sh-3.2$ which wkhtmltopdf    # Or try:
sh-3.2$ echo $PATH
sh-3.2$ exit
```

(In your case, you can do a `sudo docker exec -it <containerIdOrName> sh`)

The same issue adds:

> What I ended up doing was [downloading the dmg directly from `wkhtmltopdf`](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) and that seemed to do the trick.

That means you might have to create a new image from the current one, installing `wkhtmltopdf` that way (with the dmg package)

[`jsonfry`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/408528/jsonfry) what installing wkhtmltopdf as a service container means: [`openlabs/docker-wkhtmltopdf-aas`](https://github.com/openlabs/docker-wkhtmltopdf-aas) illustrates the installation process.

Comment: I installed it from the Ubuntu .deb so I do have wkhtmltopdf in my /usr/local/bin and I can run it from shell as root. I think the issue is that as I installed it under root the Docker container can't see it, but I'm not sure how to go about installing it in such a way that the Docker container can see it?

Comment: @Pancakes did you installed it on the host, or in a docker image with a dockerfile?

Comment: I installed it on the host, not in a docker image. How would I go about installing the package in the docker image? Sorry, I'm new to Docker and relatively inexperienced with Linux.

Comment: @Pancakes you can see an example in https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/openlabs/docker-wkhtmltopdf/dockerfile/: a dockerfile can build an image, which can be run as a container, in order to have an isolated (and reproducible) environment with `wkhtmltopdf` in it.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. Instead if mucking about inside my existing NodeJS+Express container what I ended up doing was installing the openlabs wkhtmltopdf as a service container and just accessing that.

Comment: Hey @Pancakes I'm trying to do the same things as you, I'm also quite new to Dokku / Docker. Could you elaborate on what installing wkhtmltopdf as a service container means, and how you use that from your node app? It's probably a really silly question...

Comment: Sure, it's actually really easy. There's a dockerfile which somebody has already made which basically does it all for you. Just follow the instructions here: https://github.com/openlabs/docker-wkhtmltopdf-aas

Comment: It was indeed a silly question! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I got into the same issue as you did. I didn't want to run wkhtmltopdf in another container nor did I want to change the code to use remote calls. Since downloading wkhtmltopdf using apt-get plugin may result in a package that throws errors, I have created a new plugin that should set up wkhtmltopdf in the dokku container for you.

It is licensed using MIT license so feel free to do whatever you want. Hopefully it will help somebody.

URL: https://github.com/mbriskar/dokku-wkhtmltopdf